# Color cycling for multiple matplotlib pyplot contour plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors

It is possible to cycle line colors with basic plots in `matplotlib.pyplot`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_prop_cycle(plt.cycler('color', ['c', 'm', 'y', 'k']))

x = np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, 50)
for f in [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]:
    ax.plot(x, np.sin(x * f))
plt.show()
```

This results in each partial sinewave plot having the next color from the cycler list, and it will wrap as necessary:

[image: Figure 1]

I am using the `contour` plot to draw a single contour. For each case I want to draw a single contour but I want the color shown to automatically cycle through a specified palette (so I can show a readable color-coded legend). However `ax.set_prop_cycle` doesn't seem to have the same effect here:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_prop_cycle(plt.cycler('color', ['c', 'm', 'y', 'k']))

x = np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, 50)
y = np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, 50)
z = np.zeros((len(x), len(y)))

# simple function to create useful contours:
def get_z(x, y, f):
    for i, u in enumerate(x):
        for j, v in enumerate(y):
            z[i, j] = (f * u) ** 2 + (f * v) ** 2
    return z

# plot for multiple values of `f`
for f in [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]:
    ax.contour(x, y, get_z(x, y, f), levels=[1], linewidth=2)
plt.show()
```

[image: Figure 2]

Each plot (ring) has the same color - it hasn't automatically cycled. I would like to have each plot a different color. I know that each "full" contour plot does cycle through colors for each contour drawn as part of a single plot, but in my case I'm just drawing a single contour at a fixed "level".

Is there a reasonably straightforward way to do this without explicitly specifying a color for each plot? I eventually plan to plot a dynamic number of plots, so it is not really practical to specify them all, and I need it to wrap around when required.

Perhaps there is a way to set or rotate the starting offset of a contour plot's color map?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the keyword `colors` in `plt.contour`. I don't know if this is the best possible solution, but I wrote a small cycler function for your color values, so that I can feed them to `plt.contour` upon each iteration of the `for`-loop:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
##ax.set_prop_cycle(plt.cycler('color', ['c', 'm', 'y', 'k']))

x = np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, 50)
y = np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, 50)
z = np.zeros((len(x), len(y)))

# simple function to create useful contours:
def get_z(x, y, f):
    for i, u in enumerate(x):
        for j, v in enumerate(y):
            z[i, j] = (f * u) ** 2 + (f * v) ** 2
    return z

def col_cycler(cols):
    count = 0
    while True:
        yield cols[count]
        count = (count + 1)%len(cols)

# plot for multiple values of `f`
col_iter = col_cycler(['c','m', 'y','k'])
for f in [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]:
    ax.contour(x, y, get_z(x, y, f), levels=[1], linewidth=2, colors=next(col_iter))
plt.show()
```

The result looks like this:

[image: contour plots]

Tested on Python 3.5

Comment: Ah, nice use of a perpetual generator function - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you anyway loop over your parameters, you may simply loop over the colors at the same time.

```
# plot for multiple values of `f`
for f, c in zip([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], ['c', 'm', 'y', 'k']):
    ax.contour(x, y, get_z(x, y, f), levels=[1], linewidth=2, colors=c)
```

Or, if the number of plots is unknown,

```
colors = ['c', 'm', 'y', 'k']
for i,f in enumerate([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]):
    ax.contour(x, y, get_z(x, y, f), levels=[1], linewidth=2, colors=colors[i%len(colors)])
plt.show()
```

The argument not to be wanting to "explicitly specify a color for each plot" therefore would only make sense if no loop is used.

So to obtain the same result without a loop, you can specify several levels to the same contour plot and use a colormap.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x = np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, 50)
y = np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, 50)
z = np.zeros((len(x), len(y)))

# simple function to create useful contours:
def get_z(x, y, f):
    for i, u in enumerate(x):
        for j, v in enumerate(y):
            z[i, j] = (f * u) ** 2 + (f * v) ** 2
    return z

colors = ['c', 'm', 'y', 'k']
levels = 1./np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0][::-1])**2
cmcol =  zip(plt.Normalize(levels.min(), levels.max())(levels),colors[::-1])

cmap=matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("m", cmcol)
cont = ax.contour(x, y, get_z(x, y, 1), levels=levels, linewidth=2, cmap=cmap)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. In my simple example I use a loop, but in reality I need to draw plots "on demand" and the loop isn't so explicit. However I do take your point that the color can be specified as a parameter to `contour`. I suppose what I was really looking for is whether an automatic "base color" cycling feature exists, as it does for line plots etc.

Comment: Also, interesting idea to combine the data into one plot.